# how to call method in background in application iphone?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have to call sentRequest method from background. If sendRequest work is done then i have to call splash screen in iphone. I am doing this but this not working proper in dispatch_async. I am calling this CheckForUpdatesModal class for getting all value from background then call view controller. But if i put breakpoint and show, then it is calling only sendrequest method. It not calling this method

```
-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection pleasehelp me here what is wrong some give me this ans to follow dispatch and my xcode version is4.2
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions { 


                                      [BaseModalcopyDatabaseIfNeeded];
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND, 0), ^{ 
            NSLog(@"pradeep"); // Here you can define your code to execute in  background.}); 

            CheckForUpdatesModal *CFUM = [[CheckForUpdatesModal alloc]init];
            [CFUM sendRequest];
            [CFUM release];


        });

             self.SSView = [[[SplashScreenView alloc] initWithNibName:@"SplashScreenView" bundle:nil] autorelease];          
            self.window.rootViewController = SSView;
           [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
           return YES;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :-

```
 dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_HIGH, 0ul);

 dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        CheckForUpdatesModal *CFUM = [[CheckForUpdatesModal alloc]init];
        [CFUM sendRequest];
        [CFUM release];

    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       //SHOW UR SPLASH SCREEN HERE
    });
});
```